# Python update dictionary value list with another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
dict1 = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 'key2': ['val3', 'val4']}
dict2 = {'val1': ['a', 'b'], 'val3': ['c', 'd']}
```

How do I update the values in `dict1` from `dict2` to get the following updated `dict1`?

```
{'key1': ['a', 'b', 'val2', 'c', 'd'], 'key2': ['c', 'd', 'val4']}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may loop over every pair of first dict and replace each value by the list pointed in `dict2` if exists, else keep the value. That can be done nicely with `dict.get`, that will return the list of new values to use or `[value]` which is the actual value

```
dict1 = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 'key2': ['val3', 'val4']}
dict2 = {'val1': ['a', 'b'], 'val3': ['c', 'd']}

for key, values in dict1.items():
    new_values = []
    for value in values:
        new_values.extend(dict2.get(value, [value]))
    dict1[key] = new_values

print(dict1)  # {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'val2', 'c', 'd'], 'key2': ['c', 'd', 'val4']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use nested comprehensions:

```
dict1 = {'key1': ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'], 'key2': ['val3', 'val4']}
dict2 = {'val1': ['a', 'b'], 'val3': ['c', 'd']}

dict1 = { k1:[v2 for v1 in values1 for v2 in dict2.get(v1,[v1])] 
          for k1,values1 in dict1.items()}

print(dict1)
{'key1': ['a', 'b', 'val2', 'c', 'd'], 'key2': ['c', 'd', 'val4']}
```